# Characterize the elements of a set of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given $$M = \{x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c \in\mathbb Z_3[x]\}$$ and given $$A=\{f \in M \mid\overline{1} \text{ is a root of }\ f\}.$$

The exercise asks to characterize (tell) what are the elements of $A$ and how many of them there are. My first attempt at solving this exercise was by using Ruffini's rule:

I divided $$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$$ by $$x-1$$ and the result is $$(x^2+\overline2 ax + \overline2 x + b)(x-\overline1) + c \in\mathbb Z_3[x]$$Is this a correct solution for this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all polynomials $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ such that $1+a+b+c=0\bmod3\ \ (*)$. Pick any $a$ and any $b$, then $(*)$ holds iff $c=2-a-b\bmod3$. So we have a total of 9 solutions. If you want them explicitly:

$x^3+2,x^3+x+1,x^3+2x$,

$x^3+x^2+1,x^3+x^2+x,x^3+x^2+2x+2$,

$x^3+2x^2,x^3+2x^2+x+2,x^3+2x^2+2x+1$.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain me how did you get those 9 solutions?

Comment: I thought I had. If the polynomial is $f(x)$ we want $f(1)=0$. So we write that out explicitly to get $1+a+b+c=0\bmod3$. Now whatever values we pick for $a,b$ we can always find just one value for $c$ which satisfies that. So take $a=b=0$, we need $c=2$. That is the first polynomial $x^3+2$. Take $a=0,b=1$, then we need $c=1$, that is the second polynomial $x^3+x+1$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I now understand what you mean.